# package collada_parser: dae.h not found

Tags: ros, catkin-make, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to build ROS from source. The system I am using is:

Ubuntu 13.10

ROS groovy desktop-full

I used this guide to build the system: [I have no karma to post the link]

Ubuntu is a fresh install from disk.
Compiling went well, except that the dependency on the libyaml parser was not solved, I installed those packages and it worked, however when trying to build the collada_parser packages, I get the following error:

```
kempenaarjj@ce011:~/ros/catkin_ws$ cd /home/kempenaarjj/ros/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser && 

/home/kempenaarjj/ros/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o
/home/kempenaarjj/ros/catkin_ws/src/robot_model/collada_parser/src/collada_parser.cpp:45:17: fatal error: dae.h: No such file or directory
 #include <dae.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/src/collada_parser.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/collada_parser.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The collada packages I got installed on the system(either via the rosdep dependency command or by manually using apt-get:

```
kempenaarjj@ce011:~/ros/catkin_ws/build_isolated/collada_parser$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep coll
collada-dom-dev                 install
collada-dom2.4-dp               install
collada-dom2.4-dp-base              install
collada-dom2.4-dp-dev               install
```

Also a dae.h is present on the system:

```
kempenaarjj@ce011:/$ find -name dae.h
./usr/include/collada-dom2.4/dae.h
```

I already found that there were tickets regarding this in the bug tracker, however they do not state a fix.
Which dependency do I need to install here in order to make this package work?

Regards,
Jan Jaap

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136881/package-collada_parser:-dae.h-not-found/) by [JanJaap](https://answers.ros.org/users/12941/janjaap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) on 2014-04-28**:
I have a similar problem on OSX 10.8. dae.h is installed by homebrew in /usr/local/include/collada-dom2.4 [EDIT] never mind, it looks like I just add to re-run CMake for it to find the collada-dom-config.cmake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My solution was to edit CMakeLists for that package and change the version from 2.3 to 2.4 and then it worked

---

Originally posted by [Evgeniya](https://answers.ros.org/users/26706/evgeniya/) with karma: 36 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J. Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/29555/j.-santos/) on 2017-03-03**:
It worked for me too. I edited the `src/robot_model/collada_parser/CMakeLists.txt`.